# Scala code analysis with Sonarqube for maven build

Tags: scala, jenkins, sonarqube, devops, lint

We are trying to lint Java and Scala code with Sonarqube. Java code is analysed quite efficiently but with respect to Scala project, I use the same command

```
mvn sonar:sonar
```

along with the scoverage plugin. I get no output as displayed below. How to setup with sonarqube to scan Scala code? or is there any other lint tool that is more efficient for a Jenkins CI pipeline?

[image: sonarqube output for Scala code]

Comment: Have you installed the [SonarScala plugin](https://www.sonarsource.com/products/codeanalyzers/sonarscala.html) into SonarQube? After ver 6.7.(?), SQ will analyze all languages for which it has language analyzer plugins installed.

Comment: I would recommend you to use [this](https://github.com/mwz/sonar-Scala) open source plugin, instead of the official one. - Disclaimer: I was a maintainer of that project.

Comment: @IanW Yes i did, but the scala lines don't get analyzed, I'm trying with the plugin provided by Luis Miguel

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I did use the plugin you provide, i'm not sure why my scala code is not analyses as the UI shows no signs of it, line count doesn't show up scala code lines. is there dependencies to add in pom file or sonar.props ?

Comment: What us your SQ (and plugins) versions? Sample sonar.props?

Comment: @SanjayM.P. did you check out [this example](https://github.com/mwz/sonar-scala/blob/master/examples/mvn/scala-java)?

Comment: @IanW SQ version 7.9.1 community, plugin for sonar is sonar-scala_2.12-7.8.0-assembly.jar ! Properties are default once!

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez, Yes Luis that example works fine, but my project is similar to the multi module example, which actually fails during a build.      `[INFO] compiler plugin: BasicArtifact(com.sksamuel.scapegoat,scalac-scapegoat-plugin_2.12,1.3.9,null)
[ERROR] scalac error: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test-scala-module/module1/target/scoverage-classes does not exist or is not a directory
[INFO]   scalac -help  gives more information`

Comment: @SanjayM.P. I would recommend you to create a reproducible example and open an issue in the project.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Sure Thanks ! :)